# MySQL - MyISAM tables Perforamce issue

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, percona

Below is my setup:

One primary and Two standby setup.
Application connecting to standby read-only nodes with a load balancer.
We are having approx., 600 connections at any given time on both the nodes, performing SELECT.
DB size - 3GB
Application tables - MyISAM engine tables

Below is my configuration on both RO nodes:

## MyISAM

```
key_buffer_size                     = 24G
myisam_sort_buffer_size             = 16M
sort_buffer_size                    = 16M
read_buffer_size                    = 32M
```

## Network

```
max_allowed_packet                  = 256M # default 16M
wait_timeout                        = 28800
skip_name_resolve                   = ON
max_connections                     = 1200
max_user_connections                = 1000
```

## Network

```
max_allowed_packet                  = 256M # default 16M
```

However, we are still facing very poor performance on RO nodes.
Kindly request any advise on the tuning part.

Regards
Srikanth

Comment: MyISAM is terrible and outdated and has very limited tuning options. Is using InnoDB an option?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Turn on the slowlog with a low value for `long_query_time`.  Then, let's speed up the "worst" queries.  [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone.

We initially had RAM of 24GB. Which was increased to 128GB, still no luck.
Moving all table to innodb solved the issue.

Comment: Good idea to convert to InnoDB. Remember to unconfigure your large `key_buffer_size`. If you don't have large MyISAM tables anymore, that's just a waste of memory.

Comment: 20% of RAM for `key_buffer_size` is a good starting value.  You had it the same size as RAM, that was _terrible_.